# Limit simultaneously logged on user devices count

Tags: java, php, security

Question.

How do sites, for example Netflix, implement features such as "only 2 devices is allowed to log on at the same time"?

My understanding.

User table in the database would have a "logon_count" column. Session table records session id, username, last action and so on.

multiple layers of checks to match session cookie or logon count or clean out idled session will be performed based on what user can provide upon access the URL.

But.

Say a user wants to beat the validation mechanism. Login as normal, somehow record the valid cookie and distribute/replicate it on multiple devices. Free Netflix for everyone.

When source ip is not reliable and HTTP headers can be forged, how can the server side code tell whether each session is from a unique device and thus enforce the concurrent logon restriction?

Cheers,
Ralph

Answer (score 3):

Regardless of how Netflix implements this solution, let's consider the general solution to such a problem more abstractly.

First, you need to be able to separate between what you call a *session*, which is primarily just used to retain user-application state, and the mechanism that authenticates the user when they are playing a video. Of course, if the server just correlates the session cookie that's supplied by the client directly to a device this entire solution falls apart, because as you deduced we could just easily copy the cookie to another client.

There are two requirements to solve this problem in a more general way.

1. When a video is being played the server must have a way to authenticate the client
2. The authentication mechanism must not be re-usable by any other client

Logging into Netflix itself is moot, because that's an application state. It's an entirely different problem to solve. You already know how to solve that problem, clearly. The authentication of the user when they actually request to play a video is the other problem you're asking about.

This requires something that *cannot* be reusable by multiple clients, as such it could be implemented as a [nonce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce). This is a cryptographic token that can only be used *once*.

Imagine the user downloads the video in chunks (30 second buffers). With each request to the server to download one chunk of the video, the server expects a token from the client (this is the nonce that cannot be re-used), and verifies it on the server-side. If it checks out, it sends the client back the chunk of video along with a *new token*. This can continue to happen throughout the duration of the video. Such that if another client were to copy this token and attempt sending it to the server, the server will not accept any future requests with that same token and in theory this prevents multiple devices from accessing multiple videos (*from the same account*) at the same time.

## A practical, but *contrived* example

To demonstrate, let's imagine the user logs into your application like so.

```
session_start();
if ($user->authenticate($username, $passwrod)) {
    $_SESSION['user_id'] = $user->id;
}
```

This gives your application a way to retain the client's state between HTTP requests, which is fine. However, when the user asks to play a video, something else must happen to generate the nonce.

```
$nonce = base64_encode(random_bytes(128));
$_SESSION["nonce"][$nonce] = false;
echo json_encode(["buffer" => $videoBufferData, "token" => $nonce]);
```

Let's just imagine for a second, that this code sends some API response that provides the user with the 30 second video buffer as a payload and the token in a JSON response. When the user requests the next 30 second buffer, it must match the token stored in the session.

```
if (empty($_SESSION["nonce"][$_POST["token"]])) {
    $_SESSION["nonce"][$_POST["token"]] = true; // invalidate the current nonce
    // generate a new nonce
    $nonce = base64_encode(random_bytes(128));
    $_SESSION["nonce"][$nonce] = false;
}
```

Now each time we accept a nonce that hasn't yet been used, we also generate a new nonce for the next play load. Even if the user copies the session cookie to another client, they will never be able to play videos concurrently this way. Because once one device uses a token, the other device with the same session still cannot re-use that same token on the next request **and** it wouldn't be able to receive the *new* token for continuing to play the video. So they will impede upon one another.

Comment: Thank you for this complete answer. I have never thought about this real time token solution, probably because it might be a bit too big for the size of the issue..?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that exactly, however the concept of a nonce is no different than the concept of a CSRF token, for example. Both things prevent multiple clients from trying to tamper with the same session state.

Answer (score 1):

Netflix doesn't depend on the `logon_count` but on the `requesting_video_count` (or something similar). So even if the account cookies are shared, it wouldn't matter. You can log on from as many devices as you like, you can just view videos simultaneously from up to two devices.

Comment: Great idea! Definitely solves the issue. But, how do we define whether a video is being played or not? If a user finishes a complete movie, then the requesting_video_count is updated. What if user just closed the page without finishing, pausing or stopping the movie. This would count as a live "movie watching session" or not?